# Question about ssh

Tags: ssh

If you ssh into your raspberry pi, and run something (a .sh program for example) in the ssh window, and then close the ssh window, will the program continue to run, or will it terminate? One example would be downloading something onto the raspberry pi through command line ssh. 
Thanks for helping a noob out.
Cheers

Comment: this is pretty much offtopic here, could you please be so kind to ask questions like this on Linux&Unix stackexchange?

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29641/19949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the window will terminate the SSH session, which will in turn terminate the command.

You can prevent this by running the command inside a `screen` or `tmux` session.

Comment: as an extension to that question, if you are for instance editing a file through ssh, and at the same time editing the file on the raspberry file, and you saved both files, which file would overwrite which.

Comment: While it is recommended to put new questions not in the comment section of old question but to phrase them as new questions and this question is not RPi specific and would therefore better fit the Linux&Unix.SE: It's highly unlikely that the file will be written "at the same time". So editing the file in two text editors will simply result in a file with the content of the later save.

Answer (score 1):

It will terminate, if you don't specifically tell it not to. Apart from `screen` and `tmux`, research `nohup`.