# SSH into a running instance of an application

Tags: boot, ssh, pi-2, c++

I have developed a line-following vision application for the raspberry pi, and I want it to run always, as the Pi is connected to a robot.
I know how to edit the rc.local file so that the application will run on boot, but I also need to be able to SSH into the Pi in order to change some parameters as the program is running. So how do I SSH into a running instance of an application?

Comment: Related if not dupe https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29641/19949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to `screen` is `tmux`.

You could get it instantly using

```
apt-get install tmux
```

Works similar to Screen but has been more up-to-date compared to `screen`

#### General Idea with tmux

1. open a session : `tmux new-session -d -s mySession` (here `-d` is for detached mode which lets you run the application in the backend)
2. In the same session open a new window: `tmux new-window -d -n 'windowName' -t mySession:1 'yourCommandsGoHere with the Quotes'`(`-n` is to name this new window and `-t` is for you to refer to which instance of the session is running)
3. Follow step 2 as for as many applications that you need to run
4. since all the sessions and windows are detached you could login to the pi any time and do the following to know the following:

To check which sessions are still available

```
tmux ls
```

to attach a particular session

```
tmux attach -t mySession
```

Once inside you could check all the applications using the `ctrl+b 0-9` (press `ctrl`+ `b` first and then the number)

In the end if need be you can kill sessions using:

```
tmux kill-session -t mySession
```

`tmux` has a very well descripted `man` page (use `man tmux`) and plenty of help online with great cheatsheets like [this](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058)

Comment: Thank you! Now how would I automatically setup a session that starts a c++ application when booting?

Comment: put the session you want to create in a `bash` script and execute the c++ code you want to run in the script itself. 
if you want to run it at startup try keeping it in `/etc/rc.local` or use `crontab`

Comment: when using rc.local I can see that application is actually running however when I try to attach to the session or use tmux ls nothing shows up.

Comment: have you tried using `/usr/bin/g++` because I have been facing a similar problem on this [Thread](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43375/tmux-not-executing-particular-line?noredirect=1#comment63365_43375)

Comment: I worked using @reboot in crontab when both tmux commands was on same line separated with ";". Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JesperChristensen that sounds great can you send me a pastebin or gist of the code you used. Might turn out to be useful for what I might be doing. thanks

Comment: I simply put following line into crontab -e: `@reboot tmux new-session -d -s mySession; tmux new-window -d -n 'windowName' -t mySession:1 'command'` - when using one line only it works flawlessly. When Pi has restarted type in `tmux attach` and the window is there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Run your program under GNU screen :

`screen -S mysession -d -m myapp`

Now you can SSH into your Pi and switch to your app

`screen -DR mysession`

Added bonus is that your program doesn't die with your SSH connection.