# tmux not executing particular line

Tags: bash

I am running two mesh-networking daemons, namely [A.L.F.R.E.D.](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/alfred/wiki) and [BATADV-VIS](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/alfred/wiki/Batadv-vis) on **Raspberry Pi-2**. BATADV-VIS is dependent on ALFRED hence I am using `tmux` to run them as a complete session.

I have created a bash file which I call from the `/etc/rc.local`. The details are as follows:

```
# !/bin/sh
tmux new-session -d -s piSession

tmux new-window -d -n 'alfredHere' -t piSession:1 'alfred --interface wlan0' 
# the line above doesn't get executed when called from /etc/rc.local

tmux new-window -d -n 'batvisHere' -t piSession:2 'batadv-vis -s'
```

the above bash file is in `/home/pi/` folder

When I do the following `tmux ls` I only get *2 Windows* where infact I am expecting *3 (1 x alfred running + 1 x batadv-vis running + 1 normal)*

when I do the following `tmux attach` I **do not** see the `alfred --interface wlan0` at all and the only other window open (except a common terminal session) is running `batadv-vis -s`.

Why is the line getting skipped or not being executed?

#### Observation

when I run the script from the `/home/pi/` folder as following:

```
bash /home/pi/path/myScript.sh
tmux ls
```

It shows *3 Windows*  and then everything works perfectly. Why isn't it triggering the 2nd line in case of a call from `/etc/rc.local` ?

Comment: cannot add `tmux` tag since don't have enough Reputations

Comment: Have you checked that the command works without tmux from rc.local?

Comment: @Shan-Desai: I have added the tag for you.

Comment: @Craig Hi will have a look at it but it should work because I have another stand alone bash script in `rc.local` that executes perfectly

Comment: do you think adding a `wait` after opening a session and starting a window can help? @Craig

Comment: I doubt it.  The man page says that alfred runs as daemon. If that is the case it is probably forking and exiting immediately. When that happens the tmux window is closed.

Comment: to verify @Craig you can add `; read` to the end of the command and look whether the tmux window is expecting input (and closes on pressing enter)

Comment: Try adding this before the second tmux command `tmux set-option -t piSession set-remain-on-exit on` That should prevent the window from closing when the command exits.

Comment: @Craig I tried `tmux set-option -t piSession set-remain-on-exit-on` as you mentioned now the call works from the `/etc/rc.local` but the message reads on the ALFRED window : `pane is dead`.

but running from `/home/pi/` with `bash` command works well again.

Comment: I found a rough end thing around __ALFRED__ and __BATADV-VIS__ both of them are `start-stop-daemon` types and can be run using the following:
`start-stop-daemon -b --start --exec /usr/local/sbin/alfred -- -i wlan0`
`start-stop-daemon -b --start --exec /usr/local/sbin/batadv-vis -s`
but even though I keep them in a bash script and run the same script via `rc.local` __ALFRED__ doesn't execute but batadv-vis does. 
sadly only way I can trigger it is through and ssh login :( 

any tips on how to start `start-stop-daemon` on bootup?

Comment: still no luck with this I tried putting the scripts in `bin/` in the `$HOME` folder and changed the `.bashrc` script by setting the path variables as follow:
`export PATH=$PATH:bin/` in both the __root__ and `/home/pi` folder I still cannot run the Daemons on start up nor with `crontab` with `@reboot` 

only make believe way is I need to `ssh` into the pi and trigger it by myself.