# If I connect to my Pi via SSH and install a python package using pip, will it continue to install if I end the SSH connection?

Tags: ssh, pip

I'm currently trying to install pandas on my raspberry pi, which I've connected to using an SSH connection, using pip. This is taking a long time, and my laptop has gone to sleep (ending the ssh connection to the Pi). Will the package continue to install, despite the connection dropping out?

If this has not ended the install, can I ssh back into the Pi again and check the status of the install?

Also, would the download of this package (initiated from my laptop) have used the Pi's wifi connection or the internet connection of my laptop?

Comment: Not Pi specific.  I suggest you launch pip using `nohup`.

Comment: You should be using `pip3` for python3 modules. Python2 is end-of-life since January 2020.

Comment: While the question may sound different the solution is the same: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29641/19949

Answer (score 3):

No it will not.  When your SSH session ends, any processes attached to that session will be terminated.

There are a couple of solutions but the one I use most often is the nohup command.

For example, to install using pip this way, the command would look like:

```
nohup pip3 install boto3 &
```

The nohup tells Linux to run detached and the trailing & tells it to run in the background.  Once you start like this any output will be found in the nohup.out file in the folder you start it in.

Answer (score 2):

As already said if you finish the **ssh** connection then also all running programs you have started in the foreground without additional process management will also terminate. For my opinion the simplest way to avoid this is to use a terminal multiplexer like **screen** or **tmux**. I prefer **screen**.

After login with `ssh` you can start as first `screen`. If not available just install it with `sudo apt install screen`. You will find a usual terminal console but with additional features. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you can manage `screen`, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> you will get help. Within screen just start your application. Then detach from screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and logout from `ssh`. You application is still running within `screen`. Login again with `ssh` and reattach with `screen -r`. You will find your application with its output that has run and maybe finished without interruption.

With `ssh` you are managing the RasPi, not your laptop. So there is also the internet connection used from the RasPi.